# Installation and configuration of Java 3D in ubuntu

Tags: java, programming, netbeans

My java 3d project using netbeans is running fine in my windows environment. But when I run project in Ubuntu 12.04 it shows this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
```

This is because I don't know how to install and configure Java 3D in Ubuntu.

I tried

> sudo apt-get install libjava3d-java

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You seem to be missing the path to the J3D library. Are you using an IDE or compiling from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Go to NetBeans and open your project, then right click on the **Libraries** folder and select **Add JAR/Folder...**. In the menu that shows up navigate to `/usr/share/java`, select the j3d jars and click **OK**. Now try to recompile your project, the missing library errors should be gone.